# windows 10 как закрыть зависшее полноэкранное приложение?

Tags: windows, windows-10

бывает зависает какая то игра и  не реагирует на alt+f4,
 крестик в миниатюре и кнопку закрыть окно на панели задач.
диспетчер задач открыть не получается, потому что зависшая программа выводится поверх всех окон.
Приходится выходить из системы и заходить заново.

кто-нибудь знает решение проблемы?

Comment: А если Ctrl+Alt+Del и в окошке выбрать «Start task manager»?

Comment: это тоже самое что и ctrl+shift+esc

Comment: Я сейчас на Win7, там Ctrl+Shift+Esc не запускает диспетчер задач

Comment: у всех запускает а у тебя нет? :D

Comment: Хм, и правда, запустил. Ну тогда вы, думаю, могли бы описать в вопросе, помогает ли вам эта комбинация клавиш.

Comment: а в виндовсе не помогает поставить мешьшее время ожидания зависших приложений?

Answer (score 10):

Как закрыть все зависшие программы в Windows 10

```
Нажмите Win + R.
Введите следующую команду:
taskkill.exe /F /FI "status eq NOT RESPONDING"

Нажмите Enter.
```

Все зависшие программы будут принудительно закрыты.
Как создать ярлык для закрытия всех зависших программ

```
Кликните по рабочему столу правой клавишей мыши.
Выберите пункт Создать, затем Ярлык.

В строку расположения объекта введите следующую команду, после чего нажмите Далее:
taskkill.exe /F /FI "status eq NOT RESPONDING"
```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

```
Дайте ярлыку любое комфортное для вас название и нажмите Готово.
```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

Если зависла графическая оболочка Windows, тогда ярлык не поможет.
**Как добавить системное сочетание клавиш для закрытия зависших программ**

Это должно помочь, если зависнет даже процесс Windows Explorer, который отвечает за часть графической оболочки Windows.

```
Нажмите Win + R.
Введите следующую команду и нажмите Enter:
shell:Start menu

Скопируйте созданный ранее ярлык для закрытия всех зависших программ в открывшуюся папку.
```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][3]][3]

```
Нажмите по нему правой клавишей мыши и выберите пункт Свойства.
Кликните на поле Быстрый вызов и зажмите на клавиатуре клавиши, которые хотите назначить в качестве сочетания.
Нажмите Применить.
```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][4]][4]

http://wp-seven.ru/instruktsii/system/windows-10-system/kak-zakryt-vse-zavisshie-programmy-v-windows-10.html

Comment: На дня нашёл старое приложение. Оно Win+R блокирует :)

Answer (score 8):

Есть лайфхак,  если приложение открывает диспетчер задач, но перекрывает собой ему доступ визуальный и никак не реагирует. Нажимаем win+tab, в левом углу кликаем "создать новый рабочий стол", перетаскиваем на его иконку диспетчер задач и спокойного оттуда убиваем "мерзкого паразита", потом закрываем созданный рабочий стол (спасибо ему за помощь) и делаем все, чтобы это не случилось вновь, или идем вообще делом заняться)

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение такой проблемы: тоже зависла игра в полноекранном режиме, кнопка виндовс работала (вызывала меню пуск) но при открытии любой другой программы того же диспетчера задач включала зависшая игра вот как я знял её - У меня виндовс 10 создал второй рабочий стол и с него в диспетчере задач снял зависшую программу. Если кому тоже поможет отпишитесь

Comment: интересное решение. для смены рабочего стола достаточно нажать 
 ^+WINDOWS+→ , правда пока проверить не удалось, но с работающими полно экранными работает